# why does my question and photo does not have same result

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to make an android quiz game that randomizes my questions and an images to help answer the question.. but the random values does not return the same after 2 attempts in the game.. randomNum is the int that i used for getting random number.. i'd like both the question to sync..

```
Random random = new Random();
//get random number between 0 to 9.
int randomNum = random.nextInt(quizArray.size());

//image
imageView.setBackgroundResource(image[randomNum]);
//pick quiz
ArrayList<String> quiz = quizArray.get(randomNum);

//set question and answer
questionLabel.setText(quiz.get(0));
rightAnswer = quiz.get(1);

//remove question

quiz.remove(0);
Collections.shuffle(quiz);

//set Choices
btn1.setText(quiz.get(0));
btn2.setText(quiz.get(1));
btn3.setText(quiz.get(2));
btn4.setText(quiz.get(3));

//remove quiz from quizArray
quizArray.remove(randomNum);
}
```

Comment: How are the `image` and `quizArray` arrays instantiated? Also, it would be a lot easier to simply make a data holder class of some sort, where you can have public fields specifying the question image, the title, an array of answers, and which choice is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you remove the quiz from your `quizArray` with this  `quizArray.remove(randomNum);` you need also to remove the related image from `image[]` table, i suggest that you use a `List` of image instead of `table` so you can also use  `image.remove(randomNum);` after `quizArray.remove(randomNum);`

I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

as B.M said, it looks like you're removing the quiz from quiz array but you're not removing the image from the image array - this is causing their indexes to be off.

Maybe you want to try using a HashMap of (quiz, image), and then grab a pair from the map with the random index.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you create a `Question` class with fields for `questionString`, `answerString`, and `image`. Then you can create a list of `Question` objects and simply removing the `Question` from the list will remove all associated question data.

```
class Question {
    public final String questionString;
    public final String answerString;
    public final byte[] image;

    public Question(String question, String answer, byte[] image) {
        questionString = question;
        answerString = answer;
        this.image = image;
    }
}
...
List<Question> questions = new ArrayList<>();
//Populate questions however
//I would suggest reading the questions from an XML file
//Instead of static array declarations for ease of use in the future

System.out.println(questions);
questions.remove(0);
System.out.println(questions);
```